# How can I set a default value to the model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to create a Invitation app which has a sender, receiver and message.
How can I set the current logged in user as a sender which is immutable?

## In the model.py

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    from_user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitations_received")
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    timestap = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} to {}: {}".format(self.from_user, self.to_user, self.message)
```

## In the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Game
from .models import Invitation
from .forms import InvitationForm

@login_required

def new_invitation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InvitationForm(data=request.POST, from_user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profiles_home')
    else:
        form = InvitationForm()
    return render(request, "arosis/new_invitation.html", {'form': form})
```

## In the forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Invitation
from django.shortcuts import render




class InvitationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invitation
```

Comment: yes, good question. I also tried to set default value of column. but not worked for me..

Comment: after your edit; what is not working? the user still not being set?

Comment: Hi, @warath-coder What should I do?

Comment: tell us more... what error message are you getting if any? is the form now saving successfully?

Comment: There is no error, and the form runs OK, but I want that the forms show the logged in user name instead of editable charfield.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply default to the current user because Django ORM is not normally aware of Django authentication system. You should either:

1) Pass the `request.user` while creating the model instance, like:

```
invitation = Invitation(from_user=request.user)
```

or

2) Use a middleware that adds the current user to the model each time it is saved. You can try one of these packages: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-audit/

Comment: Hi and thanks @Selcuk, can you explain more because I am fresh at learning Django. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it easily for myself as below:

## In the models.py:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitations_sent")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitations_received",
                                verbose_name="User to invite",
                                help_text="Please Select the user you want.")
    message = models.CharField("Optional Message", max_length=300, blank=True,
                               help_text="Adding Friendly Message")
    timestap = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} to {}: {}".format(self.from_user, self.to_user, self.message)
```

## In the views.py:

```
def new_invitation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        invitation = Invitation(from_user=request.user)
        form = InvitationForm(data=request.POST, instance=invitation)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('arosis_invite')
    else:
        form = InvitationForm(data=request.POST)
    return render(request, "arosis/new_invitation.html", {'form': form})
```

## In the forms.py:

```
class InvitationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invitation
        exclude = ['from_user']
```

## And in the template file:

I solved it really easy! by using:

```
{{ user.username }}
```